# Is there a way to get LOD from eyehots?

Tags: eyeshot

I want to implement LOD in eyeshot.
Do eyeshot have features like RayCast in your eyehot?
Or is it possible to find a list of entities displayed in the camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of Eyeshot you may find a virtual `Entity.IsInFustum()` method you can override to understand if the object is currently inside the view volume or not. This method can be called at every frame during dynamic movements.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrDoRlzru0s
Can implement functions like this video in the above way?

Comment: What you see in the video, is far from a basic frustum culling check.